# what's difference between writing element properties in CSS or directly?

Tags: html, css

Displaying a DIV using CSS:

```
div.divBg {
  background-color : red;
  width : 200px;
  height : 300px;
}
```

This displays what is set in CSS:

```
<div class = "divBg">
</div>
```

writing the same settings inside the DIV itself does not work:

```
<div background-color ="red" width = "200px" height = "300px">
</div>
```

please tell me what i am missing

Comment: use are missing - the `style` attribute. The browser has to know that you are applying some styles to it. the browser understands `height, width` as they are valid HTML Attributes. While for giving CSS properties, you need add `style` attribute and then the browser understands it and renders accordingly

Comment: thank you everybody for helping me. the answers below are correct. i didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<div background-color ="red" width = "200px" height = "200px">
```

to

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:200px;height:200px">
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be including your CSS rules in a `style` attribute:

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: i was just commenting so when they see your answer they can take note :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div Style="background-color:red;width: 200px; height: 200px;">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline css like this:

```
<div style=background-color:red; width:200px"; height:200px;>
</div>
```

You can learn more about css [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax.  CSS properties are not HTML attributes.  You need to use the `style` attribute to use CSS style.

```
<div style="background-color : red; width : 200px; height : 200px;">
</div>
```